# How to use grunt to change my HTML files to reference my minified JS and CSS instead of the uncompressed ones?

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, minify

I use grunt to compress all my JS and CSS files. Is there a way to change the HTML to reference the minified files automatically or I must change manually every time that I deploy my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I've mostly seen it done is that you run grunt on your local

1. Run grunt on your local as you're developing
2. **Always keep your HTML referencing the minified files**
3. If using git or another code repository system, check in the source files and minified files so that other developers can edit the source files and output new minified files.

But the HTML always references the minified/compressed files that grunt outputs.

Comment: I agree. Always run locally as identically to your production environment as possible. Or, If you are using a server-side templating library then you can have it auto select between minified and non-minified code.